# Wiener-Kinchin theorem for cyclostationary processes

Tags: stochastic-processes, fourier-analysis

The Wiener-Kinchin theorem states:

*The autocorrelation function of a wide-sense-stationary random process has a spectral decomposition given by the power spectrum of that process.*

$$
S(f) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty r_{xx} (\tau)  e^{-2\pi if\tau} d\tau
$$

Is there any way to adapt, relax, or make some kind of averaging to the theorem so that it can be applied to [cyclostationary processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclostationary_process)? If so, can you give me some reference?

Comment: Perhaps you can find what you are looking for by applying this simple fact:  If $X(t)$ is a wide sense cyclostationary process with period $T$, and if $U$ is an independent uniform random variable over $[0,T]$, then $Y(t) = X(t-U)$ is wide sense stationary.